# Copy a &str into an array pointer in Rust

Tags: rust, ffi

I have an FFI function that allocates and returns a `*mut ::std::os::raw::c_char` which points to an array of known length. I also have a `s: &str` which is a Rust string. I simply want to copy the contents of `s` into the char pointer **with added null byte**, kind of like a `strcpy()` in C, but I can't find an elegant way to do this in Rust. As a bonus, I'd love to do this in only one copy, without an intermediate allocation, but if this isn't possible then that's okay.

Here are my variables:

```rust
let ptr: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_char;
let s: &str;
```

I have considered:

- `std::ffi::CStr::from_ptr` to make a `CStr` representing the allocated memory, but this seems to be immutable
- Using `CString` but this seems to be for strings that Rust "owns" so I'm not sure it's applicable here, when Rust isn't responsible for freeing this array
- I could use `std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut` to create a mutable slice from `ptr`, but this is a bit low level, I was hoping for a higher level string manipulation option that adds the null for me, rather than making me do it

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: You seem to be taking the entire thing the wrong way around (which greatly confused me). There is no reason to convert the `ptr` to a string, what you should do is convert the string to a pointer, [`std::ptr::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ptr/fn.copy.html) from that to the pointer, then explicitely nul-terminate. You have to terminate by hand because `&str` is not nul-terminated, and forcing a nul-termination would require an in-place mutation (which can't be done on an `&str`) or an allocation via [`CString::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.new).

Comment: Sure, that sounds like a reasonable solution, feel free to write it up as an answer. I don't think it's fair to call my failed attempts which are not part of the question itself "the wrong way". I was simply making the point that treating this as a string copy rather than a byte copy operation *might* make this simpler by adding the null byte automatically, but if this isn't the best approach then that's totally fine.

Comment: [`copy_from_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice) is an alternative to a full pointer copy, but that requires creating a slice from `ptr`, and that in turns require that the entirety of `ptr`'s target is initialised, otherwise you'd have to use [`MaybeUninit.write_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#method.write_slice) and that's nightly only.

Comment: Use `std::ffi::CStr::from_ptr`, then `to_bytes_mut` to make it mutable, then copy the string to this using `copy_to_nonoverlapping`. Manually add a null byte at the end of the byte slice. Sounds like unnecessary conversions for a simple task.

Comment: Yes, the whole array is allocated. If using slices is neater then I will do that, although isn't that what I suggested in my third dot point?

Comment: Oh also I was a bit worried that byte copying from my Rust string to a C string won't keep encoding etc correct

Comment: @JishanShaikh I don't think there is such a method. There's only [`to_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.to_bytes).

Comment: @Migwell You're right, it is [`as_bytes_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes_mut) and not to_bytes_mut

Comment: @JishanShaikh that's a `str` method, but the thing we want to mutate here is a `CStr`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it requires unsafe because you write to some unknown pointer.

The code below assumes that C uses UTF-8 encoding.

Note, that I uses `memcpy` intentionally instead of making a slice from foreign pointer because there is no guarantee that memory by that pointer is initialized and making a slice from unintialized memory is undefined behaviour.

```rust
#![forbid(unsafe_op_in_unsafe_fn)]

use std::os::raw::c_char;

/// # Safety
/// `arr` must point to some valid memory which doesn't overlap with `s`.
/// `arr` must point to at least `known_len` bytes.
unsafe fn copy_rust_str_to_c_arr(s: &str, arr: *mut c_char, known_len: usize) {
    // Note, that panics must not be running across FFI boundaries
    // because it would be undefined behaviour.

    // But writing more bytes than allocated is also UB.
    assert!(s.len() + 1 <= known_len, "Not enough memory to copy str");
    // This is true for any modern architecture.
    assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<c_char>(), 1);
    unsafe {
        let our_ptr = s.as_bytes().as_ptr();
        // Safety: our_ptr is valid because it produced from string reference.
        // `arr` must be valid by safety requirements of function.
        // We checked length right before.
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(our_ptr, arr.cast(), s.len());
        // Set zero terminator for C.
        *arr.add(s.len()) = b'\0' as _;
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_copy() {
    use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};
    let s = "Hello, World!";
    // This would be used as a pointer from C.
    let mut dest: Vec<c_char> = vec!['\t' as _; s.len() * 2];
    unsafe {
        copy_rust_str_to_c_arr(s, dest.as_mut_ptr(), dest.len());
    }
    let dest = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(dest.as_ptr()) };
    let expected = CString::new(s).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&*expected , dest);
}
```

Also, nightly version which compiles to more-or-less same machine code.
Making a slice of `MaybeUninit`s is fine even if data by pointer is not initialized.

```rust
#![feature(maybe_uninit_write_slice)]
#![forbid(unsafe_op_in_unsafe_fn)]

use core::mem::MaybeUninit;
use std::os::raw::c_char;

/// # Safety
/// `arr` must point to some valid memory which doesn't overlap with `s`.
/// `arr` must point to at least `known_len` bytes.
unsafe fn copy_rust_str_to_c_arr(s: &str, arr: *mut c_char, known_len: usize) {
    // Note, that panics must not be running across FFI boundaries
    // because it would be undefined behaviour.

    // This is true for any modern architecture.
    assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<c_char>(), 1);
    let target: &mut [MaybeUninit<u8>] =
        unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(arr.cast(), known_len) };
    MaybeUninit::write_slice(&mut target[..s.len()], s.as_bytes());
    // Set zero terminator for C.
    target[s.len()] = MaybeUninit::new(b'\0');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I settled on this approach, where I cast the `char*` to a `&[u8]` as soon as possible, allowing me to do the copy using slices rather than pointer arithmetic. Although I was hoping to avoid this (as stated in the original question), I find working with slices is at least higher level than working with pointers.

```rust
// Convert the pointer into a slice
let dst_slice: &mut [u8];
unsafe {
    dst_slice = std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(
        ptr as *mut u8,
        len
    );
}
// Copy the string
dst_slice[0..(len-1)].copy_from_slice(s.as_bytes());
// Add the null terminator
dst_slice[len - 1] = 0;
```

Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1c3554114ec9806d07cf8c62a7b6171

Comment: This is only valid if the output string is initialized.

Comment: This would cause undefined behaviour if output pointer points to uninitialized data so I don't recommend to write code like that in abstract situation, e.g. when you don't know where exactly destination pointer from.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros Can either of you elaborate? Why would it matter if the destination that I'm writing to has initialized memory? I'm not reading from it, only writing to it.

Comment: Because even constructing a reference to unitialized data is not valid operation. It doesn't matter if you would even interact with it or how. You can read more there https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/

Comment: You can also read docs for from_raw_parts_mut: https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts_mut.html It states "data must be valid **for both reads and writes**".

Comment: Yes but as defined in the Rust docs, "valid" doesn't mean "initialised". It just means allocated memory that can be reasonably written to: https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ptr/index.html#safety